# Decode LTE RRC message (hexdump) using Tshark

Tags: lte, tshark

I have a hexdump of an LTE RRC message that I'm trying to decode using Tshark, and I can't figure out the command line syntax.

I'm trying to use the "User DLT" functionality of Wireshark/Tshark to solve this problem, which seems like the best/only way to do it.

Here's the hex dump of the message:

```
684C424C18432277700C823504640420211108EB5800
```

I first used `text2pcap` to create a .pcap file, using the "User 0 (147) DLT":

```
echo 000000 68 4c 42 4c 18 43 22 77 70 0c 82 35 04 64 04 20 21 11 08 eb 58 00 | \
    text2pcap -D -l 147 - /tmp/sib.pcap
```

Now here's where the issue is, I think. I don't know the correct syntax for the `tshark` command. Here's where I'm at:

```
tshark -V -o "uat:user_dlts:\"User 0 (DLT=147)\",\"lte_rrc\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"" -r /tmp/sib.pcap
```

And here's the output I get:

```
tshark: Invalid -o flag "uat:user_dlts:\"User 0 (DLT=147)\",\"lte_rrc\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\""
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the answer might be buried in [this answer](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/25869/tshark-and-uatuser_dlts), but it's not extremely descriptive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out; it turns out I was just using the wrong string for the payload protocol. I saw that `tshark -G protocols` returned `lte_rrc` as an option, so I thought that would be sufficient, but it wasn't. I needed to specify the specific protocol within LTE RRC: `lte-rrc.bcch.dl.sch`. So my full `tshark` command looks like this:

```
tshark -V -o "uat:user_dlts:\"User 0 (DLT=147)\",\"lte-rrc.bcch.dl.sch\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"" -r /tmp/sib.pcap
```

Unfortunately, I have so far been unable to find an exhaustive (or even remotely close to exhaustive) list of the available protocols that you can specify to the `-o` option.

Luckily, for my specific purposes, the [3GPP Protocol Decoder from http://3gppdecoder.free.fr](http://3gppdecoder.free.fr/?q=node/1) gives me a list of the cellular protocols I need. Obviously that doesn't help for other protocols, though...an exhaustive list would be nice.